# Copying / Pasting My Workbook Project To Another Computer Skews The Sheets Layout - How To Prevent The Skewing?

Tags: installation, zip, activex

I have a finished product - small workbook database coded in Excel 2007.

I've attempted to copy it from my machine to a ZIP file, place the ZIP file on the other machine and 'install' the workbook there on the C Drive. The installation and all functions as desired but the final product is visually skewed. It looks like someone has pushed a number of buttons, other controls / labels and the first few rows toward the top of the workbook. Visually 'squeezing' everything at the very top of Sheet1 toward the top boundary of the worksheet. The 'skewing effect' involves only the workbook ... nothing else.

Research on the internet indicates when a workbook is copied to be placed on another machine, the copying process fails to include all the background settings that Excel refers to on the original machine.

So .... how does one also copy all the settings that are in the background - separate from the workbook - that the workbook depends upon ?

I have already tried to implement dynamically setting the positions of the controls ... width of the columns and height of the rows .... this has not resulted in the desired effect.

Thanks.